# How to set interrupt priorities in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, uart, gpio, esp8266

I am working on  ESP8266. And I program it directly through FTDI using Arduino IDE. I am having problems with stack when both GPIO and UART interrupt occurs at same time or GPIO event occurs when UART sends or receives something. Is it possible to set interrupt priorities on Arduino?.

Comment: Please show your interrupt code.  If the stack is overflowing, interrupt priorities may not solve the problem.

Comment: problems is with stack clearing the data in it, when UART and GPIO interrupt occurs at same time

Comment: then i get garbage values with txed data.

Answer (score 4):

Interrumpts in Arduino have a predefined order of priority that can't be change. Here is is:

```
 1  Reset
 2  External Interrupt Request 0  (pin D2)          (INT0_vect)
 3  External Interrupt Request 1  (pin D3)          (INT1_vect)
 4  Pin Change Interrupt Request 0 (pins D8 to D13) (PCINT0_vect)
 5  Pin Change Interrupt Request 1 (pins A0 to A5)  (PCINT1_vect)
 6  Pin Change Interrupt Request 2 (pins D0 to D7)  (PCINT2_vect)
 7  Watchdog Time-out Interrupt                     (WDT_vect)
 8  Timer/Counter2 Compare Match A                  (TIMER2_COMPA_vect)
 9  Timer/Counter2 Compare Match B                  (TIMER2_COMPB_vect)
10  Timer/Counter2 Overflow                         (TIMER2_OVF_vect)
11  Timer/Counter1 Capture Event                    (TIMER1_CAPT_vect)
12  Timer/Counter1 Compare Match A                  (TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
13  Timer/Counter1 Compare Match B                  (TIMER1_COMPB_vect)
14  Timer/Counter1 Overflow                         (TIMER1_OVF_vect)
15  Timer/Counter0 Compare Match A                  (TIMER0_COMPA_vect)
16  Timer/Counter0 Compare Match B                  (TIMER0_COMPB_vect)
17  Timer/Counter0 Overflow                         (TIMER0_OVF_vect)
18  SPI Serial Transfer Complete                    (SPI_STC_vect)
19  USART Rx Complete                               (USART_RX_vect)
20  USART, Data Register Empty                      (USART_UDRE_vect)
21  USART, Tx Complete                              (USART_TX_vect)
22  ADC Conversion Complete                         (ADC_vect)
23  EEPROM Ready                                    (EE_READY_vect)
24  Analog Comparator                               (ANALOG_COMP_vect)
25  2-wire Serial Interface  (I2C)                  (TWI_vect)
26  Store Program Memory Ready                      (SPM_READY_vect)
```

For more, see [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30968/how-do-interrupts-work-on-the-arduino-uno-and-similar-boards).

Answer (score 0):

A little old, but ESP platform only have 2 priority levels, the hi one is for the WiFi.
Uart an Gpio have the same level.
May be you are taking too long in the interrupt routine.
Do not use uart in the gpio interrupt handing routine.